# How to label an Azure Cloud Service publish

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

When I publish a cloud service a deployment label is generated and can be seen on the Azure portal. Can I somehow set this in source control so I could see when and what has been deployed to Azure?

If the above is not possible is there some other recommended way to keep track of deployed versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a label in TFS. This can be done in Source Control Explorer by right-clicking an item and choosing Apply Label from the relevant submenu.

This is the approach I would recommend, since deploying to Azure at a given point in time is not necessarily linked to the source control versions at that point in time—it's up to you to manage it.

If you have an automated routine for your deployment, you can apply the label as part of that, for example using TF.EXE.